# Simple for loop for graph

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, graph, nodes

So I have produced a matrix B of weights and a vector b of the order in which I want to select nodes.

My `b=(3 5 1 2 4)`

Now I want to sum the weights, from the vector B, of the edges I've traversed.i.e I want to sum

```
B[3,5]+B[5,1]+...
```

So I said:

```
for(i in 1:n-1){
    s=sum(B[b[i],b[i+1]])    
}
s
```

but all this produces is output as such:

```
[1] 1
```

Have I done something silly?

Comment: What are the contents of the matrix `B` (you could post `dput(B)`, and what is `n`? (i.e. How do we know `1` isn't the correct answer?)

Comment: For starters, you probably wanted to 1) set `s = 0` before the loop, 2) change the line to `s = s + ...` within the loop, and 3) change `1:n-1` to `1:(n-1)` (otherwise you get `0,1...n-1` rather than `1,2...n-1`

Comment: @DavidRobinson 
So I currently have B as:  
 `matrix(c(12,5, 8,0,11,11,1,13,1,15,14, 4,14,12,12,1,7,8,8,13,5, 0,14,3,14), nrow=5)`

and `n=nrow(B)`

I can tell that 1 isn't correct just from looking at B (yeah should have posted that beforehand).

Thanks for the tip with (n-1), I didn't know that!

What do you mean when you say `s=s+...` ? Since I have to define 's' beforehand without having a prior value.  And yeah the for loop seems to do nothing as I now just get s=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
sum(B[cbind(head(b,-1),b[-1])])
```

And fyi, your loop should have been:

```
s = 0
for(i in 1:n-1){
    s=s + B[b[i],b[i+1]]    
}
```